# How send a pdf document from Azure Studio to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded a .pdf document in Azure Blob Storage. Now I would like to send that document to an AWS S3 bucket.
I thought to use the Azure ML Studio block "Execute Python script" with a script able to execute a POST. In fact, I have run an AWS API Gateway from sending anyway to an S3 bucket. Do you have any idea how to link the two services?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A python script withing the Azure ML module "execute python script" which contain a python POST with AWS S3 address

Comment: Check this and already posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989698/copy-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-aws-s3

Comment: It's expect on Stack Overflow that you post the code you are asking about.