# How to get blob SAS token after data factory copy task?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Having generated a file in Data Factory (using a Copy Task where the source data set is a Sql SP, and the sink is Azure blob storage) I am trying to follow the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989698/copy-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-aws-s3) to copy the file into an AWS S3 bucket. I have the Azure function working fine, but it requires the URI-with-SAS-token of the file to transfer.

How do I get the SAS Token in the ADF pipeline, please? (Alternatively, if you can suggest a better way of copying a file from Blob Storage to S3, please do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the SAS token in a key vault and get the value from key vault via web activity.
The below GIT location has the JSON code for the same:
https://github.com/NandanHegde15/Azure-DataFactory-Generic-Pipelines/blob/main/Get%20Secret%20From%20KeyVault/Pipeline/GetSecretFromKeyVault.json

Comment: Thank you - you've made me realise I'm making a conceptual error. The URI I can construct from the components I already have, but the SAS Token isn't a property of the file as such hence needing to get it from KeyVault.