# Stream 'Azure Blob Storage' file URL to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I am consuming a document-sharing API in my application, which when used, returns a "downloadUrl" for a given file located in Azure Blob Storage.

I want to take that Azure Blob Storage url, and stream the document into an Amazon S3 bucket.

How would I go about doing this? I see similar questions such as [Copy from Azure Blob to AWS S3 using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861723/copy-from-azure-blob-to-aws-s3-using-c-sharp) , but in that example they seem to have access to the stream of the document itself. Is there any way for me to simply provide S3 with the link, and have them do the rest? Or do I need to get the file on the server, and stream it as in the example above?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one case where S3 can be directed to fetch content "into" an object, and that is when the source is also an existing S3 object.  It can be in the same bucket or a different bucket, or even a different AWS region or account, as long as the calling user has permissions on both source and target.

Any other case -- such as what you are contemplating -- requires that you fetch the object from the source, yourself, and then upload it into S3... as in the example.